# Part identification - 231S 35L

Tags: identification

Please does anybody know what this is? It's a small part, three legs, spacing 1/20", body dimensions cca 3x4 mm. I have no idea, Googling "231S" did not give any appropriate results. Thanks.
[image: three-legged-part-231S-35L]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an Infineon [TLE4935L](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE49X5L-DS-v01_05-en%5B1%5D.pdf?fileId=db3a304316f66ee801173f11d5a23c96) Hall switch IC.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for Your help.